Can I copy paste Python 2.7 packages from lib/site-packages from Windows to Ubuntu?
I am moving to Ubuntu 22.04 from Windows 10 and I was wondering if I could skip installing again all the packages I did on my Windows 10 machine on Python 2.7. Is it possible to save the package folders and paste them into the Python installation folder in Ubuntu?

Short recommendation from my side, which might be considered off-topic: switch to Python 3 on Ubuntu and install all standard packages via pip. Your personal scripts probably need some updating, but it is worth the effort. Python 2.7 is outdated sind January 2020, that is over 4 years already.

Why? Simple pip freeze followed by pip install is not exciting enough?

It depends on what those packages contain. I wouldn't expect that 100% of packages would work, so if you want to save time (and frustration), then reinstall all packages for Linux, or run Python in a Windows VM or in Wine.
Details:

.dll files don't work on Linux. Linux has .so files (of different format) instead.

.pyc and .pyo files work only if the Python version and some compilation flags match exactly. This is unlikely: a random Python version (e.g. 2.7.x) on Windows won't match a random Python version (e.g. 2.7.y) on Linux.

.py files are usually system-independent, most of them will thus work unchanged.



Perhaps also think about using virtual environments so that you don't have a huge list of system-wide packages. This is unwieldy at the very least, and tends to lead to clashes sooner or later (package X requires version Y of package Z, whereas pacbage Q absolutely cannot work with that}.
